# Javascript multiple click events with different popups

Tags: javascript, html

Hi how do i do this the best/smartest way? I am trying to make a popup when one of the list items is clicked, then the div with the matching content number should popup.

```
<ul id="parent">
    <li class="options">Content 01</li>
    <li class="options">Content 02</li>
    <li class="options">Content 03</li>
    <li class="options">Content 04</li>
</ul>


<div class="popUp">
     <h2>Content 01</h2>
     <p>Somete random text</p>
</div>
<div class="popUp">
     <h2>Content 02</h2>
     <p>Some random text</p>
</div>
<div class="popUp">
     <h2>Content 03</h2>
     <p>Some random text</p>
</div>
<div class="popUp">
    <h2>Content 04</h2>
    <p>Some random text</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

I can make a click event on every li element, but how do i connect it with the different divs?

```
<script>
    parent = document.querySelectior("#parent");
    parent.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let options = e.document.querySelectorAll(".options");
    options.forEach(function (c) {
        c.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //Open the differen divs????
        }, false);
    });
}, false);

</script>
```

Comment: `parent = document.querySelectior("#parent");` there is no such ID.

Comment: @Javaish when you ask a question on SO,if the posted answer helps you, please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Yes i will :) but i have ben really bussy since the post but i will get back to the thread later today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general solution is to add a selector string as a `data-*` attribute to the `li`s that identifies the `div` to use, and then use that string.

```
<li data-div="#div1">...</li>
```

(adding `id="div1"` to the relevant div — or use any valid CSS selector that uniquely identifies the relevant div), and then:

```
options.forEach(function (c) {
    c.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var div = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-div")); // ***
        // Use `div` here...
    }, false);
});
```

Alternately, you can associate them by index if that's reliable in the document:

```
options.forEach(function(c, index) {                    // ***
    c.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".popUp"); // ***
        if (index < divs.length) {                      // ***
            var div = divs[index];                      // ***
            // Use div here
        }
    }, false);
});
```

In both cases, "use div here" is where you'd make that div "pop up," whatever you mean "pop up" to mean.

Comment: *(Doh! If you see `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` in the second example above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Could explain how this works? i mean how does the li know that it is the correct div?

Comment: @Javaish: Which "it," the first suggestion or the second?

Comment: First and second would be very much appreciated we are two guys here interested in the logic

Comment: @Javaish: Well, the first one intentionally targets a div via a CSS selector, as I said above. The second relies on the order of the `li`s being the same as the order of the `div`s. `index` in the `forEach` callback will be the index of the `li`, and of course, if we use that to index into a list of divs, we'll get the div at the matching index.

Comment: This is genious, use the dataattribute as the selector for a unique ID, my knowledge just grew thaaanks